# How can i close button on each tab in the dockpanel

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owaKl.png)

I want the close button next to the text on each tab like Image
I used DockPanel.
How can i add close button next to the text on each tab?

Comment: What do you use? A DockPanel or a TabControl?

Comment: @SomeBody
I use DockPanel. Not TabControl

Comment: We could help you much better if you show the relevant parts of your XAML code.

Comment: Use a valid theme, such as VS2012 and above, http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com/themes/existing-themes.html